# Unable to test java.util.Timer using Junit along with CountDownLatch

Tags: java, junit, timer

I am using a timer to perform some operation repetitively every 2 seconds. I am using JUnit to test this timer method.

Normally if I call the timer method, it just runs once and exits without giving me the actual results. But if I use the CountDownLatch, I get the expected result but the test never terminates or passes, it keeps on waiting for something even though the expected result is already obtained.

Is there a way to get around this problem or cancelling the CountDownLatch after some criterion is met?

Below is my code for the timer class and the JUnit test:

```
public class TimerTest {
int count=0;    
private  Timer timer = new Timer();     

void doSomething() {  
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            doSomethingElse();  
        }
    },
    1000, 2000);   

}

private  void doSomethingElse(){
    count++;
    System.out.println("the count is "+count);
    if(count>5){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }


}

}
```

Below is the Junit:

```
public class JunitTimer {
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {


     TimerTest test = new TimerTest();
     final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);        
   test.doSomething();
   latch.countDown();


   System.out.println("LCountdown is " +latch.getCount());
    latch.await();


}
}
```

Comment: As I understand the Timer spawns a new thread, but the junit doesn't have any access to it, so, the latch is meaningless. You cannot test it. What would you assert?

Comment: I am trying to query database every 10 seconds and make some decisions based on the database result. my doSomethingElse();  function is trying to achieve this task. the function should run continuously unless i receive the expected result. It runs with no error when i use the main method for testing, but not in Junit. I need to get it working in Junit because all of our tests run automatically in Jenkins during the build.I would assert any boolean values if possible.is there any other way around.

Comment: I am barely understand what exactly is your goal, but how it is designed at the moment - it is nearly impossible to test. You should refactor your code to be more modular and independent so it could be easily tested.

Comment: My goal is similar to incrementing the counter; for example when I reach 6 or similar other result, i want to exit the timer and pass the junit test, else keep on running the timer,if I was sure that i would get the result with a certain amount of time, i could loop just for that amount, since i am not sure after how much time i will receive the result,i have to use the timer to check it continuously. please suggest if there is some other simple work way around.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ScheduledExecutorService which is injected into your class, so that you could inject mock into it while testing. The real app would inject real executor.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyBoolean;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

class DatabasePoller
{
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private int count = 0;
    private volatile ScheduledFuture<?> scheduled;

    public DatabasePoller(final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler)
    {
        this.scheduler=scheduler;
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        };
        scheduled = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 1, 2, SECONDS);
    }

    private void doSomethingElse()
    {
        ++count;
        // do something useful
        if(count > 5) scheduled.cancel(false);
    }
}

public class DatabasePollerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    DatabasePoller testObject;
    @Mock
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    @Mock
    ScheduledFuture scheduled;
    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnableCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableCaptor.capture(), anyInt(), anyInt(), any(TimeUnit.class)))
                .thenReturn(scheduled);
    }
    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() throws Exception {

        testObject.doSomething();

        Runnable runnable = runnableCaptor.getValue();

        // schedule is not cancelled if invoked five times
        for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
            runnable.run();
        verify(scheduled, never()).cancel(anyBoolean());

        // sixth time should cancel scheduled task
        runnable.run();
        verify(scheduled, times(1)).cancel(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3919862 Updated the answer with unit test code

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the help. In the mean time I have found a much simpler and easy solution to this problem; below is the solution to my problem:

```
public class RepeatTest {
boolean repeat=true;
Integer count=0;
public boolean returncount(){

        count++;
        System.out.println("the count is"+count);
        if(count.equals(5)){
            repeat=false;
        }

    return repeat;
}

@Test
public void testreturn() throws InterruptedException{
    boolean flag=returncount();
    while(flag){
        flag=returncount();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A unit test which works more than 1 second is a bad unit test. Moreover, your unit test doesn't assert anything. Try to break a code to make the test red, e.g. change 5 any other number, e.g. 1 or 6.